# returning array from fetch api to reducer

Tags: javascript, node.js

This works:

```
const initialState = [
  { id: 1, title: 'This way', completed: true },
  { id: 3, title: 'array definition works', completed: true },
  { id: 2, title: 'As expected', completed: false },
];
```

the hardcoded array works as expected, but if I try to get values dynamically from async fetch api, then:

"Desperate attempt to make it work"

```
(async () => {
  initialState.push(getPostAsync('/posts').then(data =>[
    { id: 1, title: data.title, completed: true },
    { id: 3, title: 'This way doesnt', completed: false },
    { id: 2, title: 'work ', completed: false }]));
})();

export const filterForum = (forums, searchKeyword) => (
  Object.values(forums).filter(forum => forum.title.includes(searchKeyword))
)
```

×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: Can you please post that part of the code where the `forums.filter` is not a function is happening? Usually this happens when variable (in this case `forums`) where `filter` is called is not an array. I would do a `console.log(forums)` to see what values you have there in the code.

Comment: where are you using forums.filter function ?

Comment: what is the value of `forum.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchKeyword.toLowerCase())`?  Also what is the value of forums?

Comment: I see the definition of a `filterForum` function, but not how it's used. It's probably being passed an incorrect value, I guess.

Comment: from your code it looks like `forum` is an Object. ( `forum.title` gives that impression. ) If that's the case `filter` isn't a method available on it. You would need to convert it into an Array.

Comment: @ruby_newbie selectors/index.js
  Line 2:15:  'forum' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there:

you provided an uninitialized, therefore - unresolved promise as a fallback initial state.

which means in theory, in order to get the values, you need to do

```
reducer = (state = await initialState, ...)
```

**but since it is not possible**, what you really have to do is start with a hard coded `[]` state (or `{list: []}`)
and populate the next state using an [Action](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) which may be async, and feed the outcome to the synchronous reducer

full example:

```
// reducer.js

const initialState = [];

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
     case 'loadList': {
        return [...state, ...action.payload.list]; // in case payload is {list: [...]}
     }
     default:
       return state;
  }
}

// actions.js

export const loadList = () => async dispatch => { // need to install redux-thunk to get the 'dispatch' closure
  try {
    const data = fetch(...);
    dispatch({type: 'loadList', payload: {list: data}});

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

}
```

note that actions are synchronous, but can be made async using redux-thunk library. [link here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#usage-with-redux-thunk)

Comment: Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: like i said, it is not possible. In the theory you need it resolved. hold on, editing with example

Comment: Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: I added (async () => {
  reducer = (state = await initialState)
})(); but then 'state' is not defined

Comment: tweaking the code I now have 'state' is not defined no-undef

Comment: hi, please read the answer in its entirety. hint: you cannot have an async reducer state

Answer (score 0):

From your response, the `forums` variable that you are passing to `filterForum`(I would call it filterForums but W/E) is not defined.  So when you try to call .filter on it, it blows up because .filter is not defined on an undefined variable.